# Malthusian Growth Model in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am interested in modeling a Malthusian growth model in Ruby. Does anyone have any ideas, or are there any interesting libraries that cover this? Any help is appreciated.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malthusian_growth_model

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need a library for this?

```
p = 50
t = 5
r = 0.1
p *= Math.exp(r*t)
print p
```

If you want more, please be more specific.

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate the quick response!